# How to aggregate unique count with pandas pivot_table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

This code:

```
df2 = (
    pd.DataFrame({
        'X' : ['X1', 'X1', 'X1', 'X1'], 
        'Y' : ['Y2', 'Y1', 'Y1', 'Y1'], 
        'Z' : ['Z3', 'Z1', 'Z1', 'Z2']
    })
)
g = df2.groupby('X')
pd.pivot_table(g, values='X', rows='Y', cols='Z', margins=False, aggfunc='count')
```

returns the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): ... 
AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'index'
```

How do I get a Pivot Table with **counts of unique values** of one DataFrame column for two other columns?
Is there `aggfunc` for count unique? Should I be using `np.bincount()`?

NB. I am aware of `pandas.Series.values_counts()` however I need a pivot table.

---

EDIT: The output should be:

```
Z   Z1  Z2  Z3
Y             
Y1   1   1 NaN
Y2 NaN NaN   1
```

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
>>> df2.pivot_table(values='X', index='Y', columns='Z', aggfunc=lambda x: len(x.unique()))

Z   Z1  Z2  Z3
Y             
Y1   1   1 NaN
Y2 NaN NaN   1
```

Note that using `len` assumes you don't have `NA`s in your DataFrame. You can do `x.value_counts().count()` or `len(x.dropna().unique())` otherwise.

Answer (score 64):

This is a good way of counting entries within `.pivot_table`:

```
>>> df2.pivot_table(values='X', index=['Y','Z'], columns='X', aggfunc='count')

        X1  X2
Y   Z       
Y1  Z1   1   1
    Z2   1  NaN
Y2  Z3   1  NaN
```

Comment: This does exactly what is required without an obscure lambda.

Comment: Note: Pandas no longer accepts rows/cols as parameters. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html

Comment: @Alper that's incorrect. Using 'count' will count all instances, not only unique ones. This reply does not answer the question.

Answer (score 45):

Since at least version 0.16 of pandas, it does not take the parameter "rows"

As of 0.23, the solution would be:

```
df2.pivot_table(values='X', index='Y', columns='Z', aggfunc=pd.Series.nunique)
```

which returns:

```
Z    Z1   Z2   Z3
Y                
Y1  1.0  1.0  NaN
Y2  NaN  NaN  1.0
```

Answer (score 13):

`aggfunc=pd.Series.nunique` provides distinct count. Full code is following:

```
df2.pivot_table(values='X', rows='Y', cols='Z', aggfunc=pd.Series.nunique)
```

Credit to @hume for this solution (see comment under the accepted answer). Adding as an answer here for better discoverability.

Answer (score 6):

- The `aggfunc` parameter in [`pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) will take `'nunique'` as a `string`, or in a `list`

  - [`pandas.Series.nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.nunique.html) or [`pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html)
- **Tested in `pandas 1.5.0`**

```py
out = df2.pivot_table(values='X', index='Y', columns='Z', aggfunc=['nunique', 'count', lambda x: len(x.unique()), len])

[out]:
             nunique           count           <lambda>            len          
Z       Z1   Z2   Z3    Z1   Z2   Z3       Z1   Z2   Z3   Z1   Z2   Z3
Y                                                                     
Y1     1.0  1.0  NaN   2.0  1.0  NaN      1.0  1.0  NaN  2.0  1.0  NaN
Y2     NaN  NaN  1.0   NaN  NaN  1.0      NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  1.0


out = df2.pivot_table(values='X', index='Y', columns='Z', aggfunc='nunique')

[out]:
Z    Z1   Z2   Z3
Y                
Y1  1.0  1.0  NaN
Y2  NaN  NaN  1.0

out = df2.pivot_table(values='X', index='Y', columns='Z', aggfunc=['nunique'])

[out]:
             nunique          
Z       Z1   Z2   Z3
Y                   
Y1     1.0  1.0  NaN
Y2     NaN  NaN  1.0
```

Answer (score 4):

You can construct a pivot table for each distinct value of `X`. In this case,

```
for xval, xgroup in g:
    ptable = pd.pivot_table(xgroup, rows='Y', cols='Z', 
        margins=False, aggfunc=numpy.size)
```

will construct a pivot table for each value of `X`. You may want to index `ptable` using the `xvalue`. With this code, I get (for `X1`)

```
     X        
Z   Z1  Z2  Z3
Y             
Y1   2   1 NaN
Y2 NaN NaN   1
```

Comment: Thank you. However I am not counting the number of occurrences of each distinct value of X, I am counting the number of distinct values in X for Y and Z.

Answer (score 1):

Since none of the answers are up to date with the last version of Pandas, I am writing another solution for this problem:

```
import pandas as pd

# Set example
df2 = (
    pd.DataFrame({
        'X' : ['X1', 'X1', 'X1', 'X1'], 
        'Y' : ['Y2', 'Y1', 'Y1', 'Y1'], 
        'Z' : ['Z3', 'Z1', 'Z1', 'Z2']
    })
)

# Pivot
pd.crosstab(index=df2['Y'], columns=df2['Z'], values=df2['X'], aggfunc=pd.Series.nunique)
```

which returns:

```
Z   Z1  Z2  Z3
Y           
Y1  1.0 1.0 NaN
Y2  NaN NaN 1.0
```

Comment: Actually, for count the frequency, pd.crosstab is preferable than pivot table.

Answer (score 1):

`aggfunc=pd.Series.nunique`
will only count unique values for a series - in this case count the unique values for a column. But this doesn't quite reflect as an alternative to `aggfunc='count'`

For simple counting, it better to use `aggfunc=pd.Series.count`

Answer (score 0):

For best performance I recommend doing `DataFrame.drop_duplicates` followed up `aggfunc='count'`.

Others are correct that `aggfunc=pd.Series.nunique` will work. This can be slow, however, if the number of `index` groups you have is large (>1000).

So instead of (to quote @Javier)

```
df2.pivot_table('X', 'Y', 'Z', aggfunc=pd.Series.nunique)
```

I suggest

```
df2.drop_duplicates(['X', 'Y', 'Z']).pivot_table('X', 'Y', 'Z', aggfunc='count')
```

This works because it guarantees that every subgroup (each combination of `('Y', 'Z')`) will have unique (non-duplicate) values of `'X'`.