# Pandas: GroupBy to DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Referring to [this very popular question regarding groupby to dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373660/converting-a-pandas-groupby-object-to-dataframe). Unfortunately, I do not think this particular use case is the most useful, here's mine:

Suppose you have what could be a hierarchical dataset in a flattened form, e.g.

```
     key    val 
0    'a'    2
1    'a'    1
2    'b'    3
3    'b'    4
```

what I wish to do is convert that dataframe to this structure

```
    'a'  'b'
0    2    3
1    1    4
```

I thought this would be as simple as `pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('key').groups)` but it isn't.

How can I make this transformation?

Comment: What if there are two ('a',    2) pairs? What should be the expected result?

Comment: @Tai then they should be there the value 2, twice

Comment: Thanks. Updated my answer :P I suggested you update your example to help people understand your problem. You can take data from my answer.

Comment: **This is a pandas `pivot_table` in disguise**; it allows counts of duplicate entries. See [How to aggregate unique count with pandas pivot_table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12860421/how-to-aggregate-unique-count-with-pandas-pivot-table), [Difference between groupby and pivot_table for pandas dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34702815/difference-between-groupby-and-pivot-table-for-pandas-dataframes).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
df.assign(index=df.groupby('key').cumcount()).pivot('index','key','val')
Out[369]: 
key    'a'  'b'
index          
0        2    3
1        1    4
```

Comment: Could you please explain how this works, as well as why you chose to make this hierarchical by assigning a value to index?

Comment: @SumNeuron , when you want ot pivot you need three para, index, column , value, In your example df, you do not have index, the cumcount is to get then index , then we can pivot your sample df to expected output

Comment: is there a way to drop the index label?

Comment: @SumNeuron adding rename_axis(None,axis=1) https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html

Comment: @Wen that ends up dropping the label `key` and keeping `index`

Comment: @Wen also, is there a way to do this with a list of values instead of just 'val' ?

Comment: @SumNeuron rename_axis(None,axis=1) and rename_axis(None,axis=0), you need to do it twice . For your extra question , can you show me the data ? Or maybe we can open a new question ?

Comment: @Wen the new question is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48265340/pandas-doing-quantile-normalization-on-a-subset-of-a-flattened-dataset-with-rep It uses a lot from what I have learned from your answer and another question :)

Answer (score 3):

what about the following approach?

```
In [134]: pd.DataFrame(df.set_index('val').groupby('key').groups)
Out[134]:
   a  b
0  2  3
1  1  4
```

Answer (score 2):

Think this should work. Note the example is different from OP's. There are duplicates in the example.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'key': {0: "'a'", 1: "'a'", 2: "'b'", 3: "'b'", 4: "'a'"}, 
                   'val': {0: 2, 1: 1, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 2}})


df_wanted = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
                df.groupby("key")["val"].apply(list).to_dict(), orient='index'
            ).transpose()


    'a'     'b'
0   2.0     3.0
1   1.0     4.0
2   2.0     NaN
```

`df.groupby("key")["val"].apply(list).to_dict()` creates a dictionary `{"'a'": [2, 1, 2], "'b'": [3, 4]}`. Then, we transfer the dictionary to a DataFrame object.

We use `DataFrame.from_dict` function. Because the dictionary contains different lengths, we need to pass in an extra argument `orient='index'` and then do `transpose()` in the end.

Reference

[Creating dataframe from a dictionary where entries have different lengths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19736080/creating-dataframe-from-a-dictionary-where-entries-have-different-lengths)

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to Pandas but this seems to work:

```
gb = df.groupby('key')
k = 'val'
pd.DataFrame(
    [gb.get_group(x)[k].tolist() for x in gb.groups], 
    index=[x for x in gb.groups]
).transpose()
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's use `set_index` and `unstack` with `cumcount`:

```
df.set_index([df.groupby('key').cumcount(),'key'])['val']\
  .unstack().rename_axis(None,1)
```

Output:

```
   'a'  'b'
0    2    3
1    1    4
```