# numpy array to pandas pivot table

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, numpy

I'm new to pandas and am trying to create a pivot table from a numpy array.

variable `npArray` is just that, a numpy array:

```
>>> npArray
array([(1, 3), (4, 3), (1, 3), ..., (1, 4), (1, 12), (1, 12)], 
      dtype=[('MATERIAL', '<i4'), ('DIVISION', '<i4')])
```

I'd to count occurrences of each material by division, with division being rows and material being columns. Example:

[image]

What I have:

```
#numpy array to pandas data frame
pandaDf = pandas.DataFrame (npArray)

#pivot table - guessing here
pandas.pivot_table (pandaDf, index = "DIVISION", 
                    columns = "MATERIAL", 
                    aggfunc = numpy.sum) #<--- want count, not sum
```

Results:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

Sample of `pandaDf`:

```
>>> print pandaDf
         MATERIAL  DIVISION
0               1         3
1               4         3
2               1         3
3               1         3
4               1         3
5               1         3
6               1         3
7               1         3
8               1         3
9               1         3
10              1         3
11              1         3
12              4         3
...           ...       ...
3845291         1         4
3845292         1         4
3845293         1         4
3845294         1        12
3845295         1        12

[3845296 rows x 2 columns]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something similar has already been asked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12862196/9754169

Bottom line, just do `aggfunc=lambda x: len(x)`

Answer (score 1):

@GerardoFlores is correct. Another solution I found was adding a column for frequency.

```
#numpy array to pandas data frame
pandaDf = pandas.DataFrame (npArray)

print "adding frequency column"
pandaDf ["FREQ"] = 1

#pivot table
pivot = pandas.pivot_table (pandaDf, values = "FREQ", 
                            index = "DIVISION", columns = "MATERIAL", 
                            aggfunc = "count")
```