# Retrieve the count of the number of different values from a pandas DF based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Dummy df:

```
columns = ['id', 'answer', 'is_correct']
data = [['1','hello','1.0'],
       ['1','hi', '1.0'],
       ['1','bye', '0.0'],
        ['2', 'dog', '0.0'],
        ['2', 'cat', '1.0'],
        ['2', 'dog', '0.0'],
        ['3', 'Milan', '1.0'],
        ['3', 'Paris', '0.0'],
        ['3', 'Paris', '0.0'],
        ['3', 'Milannnn', '1.0']]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns, data=data)
```

I want to create a new df with the following columns:

```
headers= ['id', 'number_of_different_correct_answers', 'number_of_different_incorrect_answers']
```

`id` should equal `id` from the dummy df.

Consequently, I want to retrieve the number of **different** correct answers (`is_correct == 1.0`) for each `id` and likewise for `is_correct == 0.0` (incorrect answers). With different I mean that within `id 2` we have dog twice within `is_correct == 0.0` thus it should only count as 1.

Based on the dummy df, the new df would look like this

```
id  number_of_different_correct_answers number_of_different_incorrect_answers
1   2                                   1
2   1                                   1
3   2                                   1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can drop duplicates, groupby by id and count distinct values:

```
(df.drop_duplicates(['id','answer'])
   .groupby('id')['is_correct']
   .value_counts()
   .unstack(level=1)
   .rename(columns = {'0.0':'number_of_different_incorrect_answers', 
                      '1.0':'number_of_different_correct_answers'})
)
```

produces

```
is_correct  number_of_different_incorrect_answers   number_of_different_correct_answers
id      
1           1                                       2
2           1                                       1
3           1                                       2
```

Answer (score 2):

this was answered before [Python Pandas : pivot table with aggfunc = count unique distinct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12860421/python-pandas-pivot-table-with-aggfunc-count-unique-distinct)
But it is using old versions of pandas so needs some update

```
df.pivot_table(values='answer',index='id', columns='is_correct',aggfunc=lambda x: len(x.unique())).rename(columns={'1.0':'number_of_different_correct_answers','0.0':'number_of_different_incorrect_answers'})
```