# How to create a bar plot of the number of unique values within each group

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

## the following is the data set

gm = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gerberl/6G7V0026-2223/main/datasets/gapminder.tsv', sep='\t')
```

the command that I have been using, which counts each country multiple times.

```py
sns.countplot(x=gm.continent)
plt.show
```

I can get the plot graph by making a new data frame, however there must be a way to get the graph without making a new dataframe.

The bars would be for the total number of countries in each continent, where the x-axis will be continents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The most direct way is to use [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) to get the number of unique countries for each continent, and then plot directly with [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html).

  - `pandas` uses `matplotlib` as the default plotting backend, and `seaborn` is just an API for `matplotlib`.
- This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68854282/7758804) shows how to use [`pd.DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) to get the number of unique values for each group.

  - `gm.groupby('continent')['country'].nunique()` can also be used.
- If the link to the Gapminder data no longer works, it can also be found [here](https://www.gapminder.org/data/).

```py
import pandas as pd

# load the dataset
gm = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gerberl/6G7V0026-2223/main/datasets/gapminder.tsv', sep='\t')

# create a pivot table with continent and the number of unique countires
pt = gm.pivot_table(index='continent', values='country', aggfunc='nunique')

# plot the bar cart
ax = pt.plot(kind='bar', rot=0, ylabel='Number of Countires', xlabel='Continent', legend=False)
```

[image]

#### `pt` DataFrame

```py
           country
continent         
Africa          52
Americas        25
Asia            33
Europe          30
Oceania          2
```

Answer (score 0):

When one is building visualizations it is frequently useful to create additional variables.

For this specific case, one can start by creating a dataframe with the number of countries in each continent, by using [`pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html) and [`pandas.DataFrame.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) as follows

```
df_new = gm.groupby('continent')['country'].nunique().reset_index()

[Out]:

  continent  country
0    Africa       52
1  Americas       25
2      Asia       33
3    Europe       30
4   Oceania        2
```

Then, from that newly created dataframe `df_new`, one can create the bar plot using [`seaborn.barplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html). Depending on the requirements can have a variety of adjustments. As OP didn't specify strong opinions, the following will do the work

```
ax = sns.barplot(x='continent', y='country', data=df_new)
ax.set_title('Number of countries in each continent')
ax.set_xlabel('Continent')
ax.set_ylabel('Number of countries')
plt.show()
```

[image]